# Can I mix post conditions and recursive functions in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, verification, tail-recursion

Is it possible to use both recur and post-condition functionality in the same Clojure function? I was hoping to throw an exception using the post-condition, but Clojure appears to be trying to wrap the exception throwing code after the recur somehow, so (just as a stupid example) functions like this cannot be evaluated.

```
(defn countup [x]
  {:pre [(>= x 0)]
   :post [(>= % 0)]}
  (if (< x 1000000)
    (recur (inc x))
    x))
```

I'm using Clojure 1.3 at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the implementation of `defn` at https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/35bd89f05f8dc4aec47001ca10fe9163abc02ea6/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L4580-L4585 you'll see that the body of a function gets modified so that tail calls get pushed out of the tail-position.  One way around this is to use an auxiliary function to call the recur'd function and put the post-condition on that instead:

```
(defn- countup* [x]
  (if (< x 1000000)
    (recur (inc x))
    x))

(defn countup [x]
  {:pre [(>= x 0)]
   :post [(>= % 0)]}
  (countup* x))

(countup 999999)
;=> 1000000

(countup -1)
; Assert failed: (>= x 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

"recur" is like "goto to the begin of the block with that parameters".

You cannot place any code after it because of it does not save things in the stack, so don't know where it came from (and what checks it should perform after running).

For example, `(loop [] (recur))` will loop forever without consuming stack.

In your example I expect `:post` to be executed once, when x==1000000.

Answer (score 1):

You can totally do this and in many cases the ability to get pre/post conditions may be worth the speed lost by not using the loop/recur special form.

The recur special form wont do it for ya because it is not really a function call. You could make your own wrapper function that does the bounds checking in pre and post conditions after all the code runs, or you can use the built in `trampoline` function and save a little effort and have the conditions checked on every iteration (you need to decide if you want that)

You can turn this into a recursive function with out blowing the stack:

```
(defn countup [x]
              {:pre [(>= x 0)]
              :post [(or (ifn? %) (>= % 0))]}
              (if (< x 1000000)
                  #(countup (inc x))
                  x))

(trampoline (countup 0))
1000000
```

This changes the post condition to ignore the intermediate cases (where it returns the function to run next) and only verify the final result.

The idea behind trampolining is to avoid blowing the stack by having each iteration of the function return the call to the next function instead of calling it directly. this way one two stack frames are used (one for the trampoline and one for the current step)

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the easiest (no trampolining or using auxiliary functions) would be something like this:

```
(defn countup [x]
  {:pre [(>= x 0)]
  :post [(>= % 0)]}
  (loop [x x]
        (if (< x 1000000)
            (recur (inc x))
          x)))

(countup 999999)
1000000

(countup -1)
; Evaluation aborted.
```

So, just inject an auxiliary loop (identical to the function signature).